# Spring data custom N1QL query returns property document to null

Tags: java, spring-data, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I'm using `spring-data-couchbase 2.1.2`, I redefined a repository with a custom query:

```
@Override
public List<PortfolioDocument> searchPortfolio() {

    CouchbaseOperations template = templateProvider.resolve(PortfolioRepository.class, PortfolioDocument.class); 

    String statement = "select META(ipdb).id AS _ID, META(ipdb).cas AS _CAS, * " + 
        "from ipdb where _class = 'com.ipdb.datamodel.document.PortfolioDocument' AND  title = 'dummytitle'";
    SimpleN1qlQuery query = N1qlQuery.simple(statement);;
    List<PortfolioDocument> portfolioDocuments = template.findByN1QL(query, PortfolioDocument.class);

    ....
}
```

`template.findByN1QL(query, PortfolioDocument.class);` returns some `PortfolioDocument` with all property to null except the id property.
If I call `template.findByOne(id);` the resulting object is ok.
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution. The correct query is:

```
SELECT META(`ipdb`).id AS _ID, META(`ipdb`).cas AS _CAS, `ipdb`.* FROM `ipdb` WHERE ...
```

The best practice is to use the methods of `N1qlUtils`, you can look at the example below:

```
Statement statement = N1qlUtils.createSelectClauseForEntity(template.getCouchbaseBucket().name()).
  from(Expression.i(template.getCouchbaseBucket().name()))
    .where(".....");
```

`createSelectClauseForEntity` and `from` methods build the a part of query.